Who was Sazz really after in “Only Murders in the Building”?
In season 04 of mystery drama series Only Murders In The Building, the podcasters are trying to solve a murder of a close friend. Meantime, a movie is being made based on their past adventures, with 3 celebrities Eugene Levy (Charles), Zack Galifianakis (Oliver) and Eva Longoria (Mabel) playing the roles of the 3 podcasters.
In episode 01, the trio visit Sazz's home, and find a set of notes on her desk, including "Looking at Charles", "Long Game" and "Sick Pup".
While working together to solve the case in episode 07, they develop a hypothesis, that the Season 04's problems started in Season 01 itself, and Sazz was on the verge of a breakthrough at the end of Season 03.
Season 04 Spoilers

Zach: For instance, uh... yeah, who poisoned Winnie? You thought it was Sting.
You know what, it wasn't Sting, and then, you just dropped it.
Eugene: Plot hole number two. The note on Jan's door.
Mabel: "I'm watching you". Just like the text message.
Mabel: It's the...
Eugene: Same person. Very good, Mabel.
Eva: Your murderer has been after you since season one.
Charles: And Sazz knew all of that. Think back to her apartment! Uh... "Sick pup". That's Winnie! "Door note". That's the note on Jan's door.
Sazz figured this all out. Maybe that's what she wanted to tell me.

But,

 At the end of Season 04, we learn that its villain had no motive until Sazz threatened to expose him, which happened after Season 01's events.
 This disproves the hypothesis that it was him who poisoned the dog and / or wrote the threatening note and that Sazz was killed because she figured it out.

But as mentioned earlier, some of the notes on Sazz' desk were about the clues related to Season 01.
So who was she really after?

It doesn't come up again in the show - which might be because it's the same kind of "plothole" it's poking fun at.
However, we learn later that:

 Sazz wrote the original script for the OMITB movie. Her notes were probably written to support the writing of the script. In fact, she couldn't have been investigating who would be coming to try to kill Charles, since Sazz was the intended target from the start.

